# C# For each statement cannot operate 'List' because of no 'Get Enumerator', How can I fix this code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, serialization, document

I have a few methods and classes but it throws an error because

> 'List' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

The first method below shows the foreach being used:

```
public static string Execute(string imagePath)
{
    var img = Cv2.ImRead(imagePath);
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> featureScores = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();


    List  features =  GetFeatures();

    AKAZE kaze = AKAZE.Create();
    Mat desc = new Mat();
    kaze.DetectAndCompute(img, null, out KeyPoint[] keyPoints, desc);

    foreach (var feature in features)
    {
        var train = new Mat(feature.Rows, feature.Cols, feature.ImgType, feature.ImgData);
        var matches = GetMatches(desc, train);
        var score = GetScore(matches);
        if (score == double.MaxValue)
            continue;
        featureScores.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>(feature.Category, score));
    }
    return featureScores.Count > 0 ? featureScores.OrderByDescending(x => (x.Value)).ToList()[0].Key : "Unknown";
}
```

The `GetFeatures()` Method below:

```
public static List GetFeatures()
{
    SharpSerializer serializer = new SharpSerializer(true);
    FileStream fs = File.Open(@"D:\NCBC\OpenCV\CustomCV\CustomCV\bin\Debug\features.bin", FileMode.Open);

    object obj = serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    List result = (List)obj;
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    fs.Dispose();
    return result;
}
```

And the information that has been Stored

```
private static ExtractedFeature ExtractFeatures(string image)
{
    Mat img = Cv2.ImRead(image);
    string category = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(image).Split('.')[0];
    Console.WriteLine(category);

    OpenCvSharp.AKAZE kaze = OpenCvSharp.AKAZE.Create();
    Mat desc = new Mat();

    kaze.DetectAndCompute(img, null, out KeyPoint[] keyPoints, desc);
    ExtractedFeature result = new ExtractedFeature()
    {
        ImgData = desc.ToBytes(),
        Cols = desc.Cols,
        Rows = desc.Rows,
        ImgType = desc.Type(),
        Category = category

    };

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `List` to the question

Comment: Why are you mixing generics and non-generics?

Comment: There's no non-generic `List` type in .NET. Where did this come from?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because 1) *The type or namespace name 'ExtractedFeature' could not be found* 2) *Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments*.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YEA4Zz.  I suspect you've wrongly copied some malformed code from a comment in https://www.tech-quantum.com/build-custom-image-recognition-part-2/ and need to return a `List<ExtractedFeature>` not a `List`, which doesn't exist.  But without a [mcve] we can't really help you.  See: [ask].

Answer (score 2):

GetFeatures() returns a `List` not a `List<T>`

You should give `List` a type such as string or `int`, that corresponds to what the list contains

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to cast an object to a type List, but you only can do it if yours underlying type is really a list or if its implements all interfaces that a List implements.

So I would recommend if to first check the type boxed in the variable with a

```
     obj is List
```

which obvisosly isn't.

So, I suggest you must try to Deserialize the FileStream to an typed object or try to infere the correctly output type of the method **Deserialize**